# Flutter Error: Type 'File' not found. What's going on here?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use `firebase_ml_vision` with `image_picker`.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyHomePage());

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    FirebaseVisionImage visionImage;

    final BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.barcodeDetector();
    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
    final ImageLabeler labeler = FirebaseVision.instance.imageLabeler(
          ImageLabelerOptions(confidenceThreshold: 0.75),
    );
    final FaceDetector faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector();

    void detections() async {
        final VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);
    }

  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    var something = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      this.visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(something);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(_image),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I am unable to use the `File` datatype and this is the error I get:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llG4N.png)

Here's what I get when I run `flutter doctor`:
[Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJofS.png)

And here's what I get when I run `flutter --version`:
[Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSGCx.png)

I'm very new to Flutter so please let me know if you need anything else.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get` after add image_picker in your project ?

Comment: @RubensMelo Yes, I did. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File type is in [dart:io](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html), which you are missing. Add `import 'dart:io';` to the top of the file.